# How to use a material-ui button with MuiThemeProvider as Popup's trigger in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use as a trigger of a Popup in React a button with custom theme:

```
 <PopUp modal trigger={
                        <MuiThemeProvider theme={buttonTheme}>
                            <Button variant="contained" color="secondary">Excluir</Button>
                        </MuiThemeProvider>
 }>
```

But when I do this, I get this error: "Failed prop type: The following props are not supported: `onClick`. Please remove them. in ThemeProvider" and "Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?". I would like to stop the error. 
The button gets colorful, but it doesn't open the Popup.

Comment: what is `PopUp`? It's not standard Material UI component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to put the tag outside the trigger.

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={buttonTheme}>
         <PopUp modal trigger={<Button variant="contained" color="secondary">Excluir</Button>>}
</MuiThemeProvider>
```